# How to migrate gerrit reviews to gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gerrit

Is there any way to migrate gerrit reviews to gitlab ? We are migrating everything to gitlab.

We have migrated the repositories but not sure about gerrit reviews

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are currently no importers for Gerrit code reviews into GitLab. There are also none listed in the [documentation for migrating projects to GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/) either.

However, given that both Gerrit and GitLab have an API, it might be possible to create an importer that lists the Gerrit equivalent to GitLab merge requests (MRs), translates the relevant data into MR data, and imports it into GitLab as one MR per Gerrit change.

- [Gerrit API for changes](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#change-endpoints)
- [GitLab API for creating an MR](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr)